Recommended way to build database to contain users and chatgpt data
I am looking to create a Rails application to interface between users and Azure ChatGPT. I will include my ERD diagram showing a couple of options in building the database tables and table associations. I am having trouble deciding which option to go with and was wondering if anyone has any feedback on which option would be better or maybe your option (3rd option) is better?
Thank you


I have no idea what "cals" and "soils" relates to .....

would a question not related directly to an answer, so that it is in the same row

@Craig "cals" and "soils" are resource groups. So a resource group represents users of a group that will be charged when using ChatGPT. Those in "cals" will be charged for their usage and those within "soils" will be charged for their usage. There is potential for more groups but right the groups are cals and soils.

As soon as you say "there is potential for more groups", then straight away that at least tells you that you should use a "users" / "resource groups" structure (rather than setting "cals" and "soils" as fields in the table).  I can almost guarantee that how soon YOU think another group might be needed will not be soon enough

Going with Option 2. As others have pointed out, with the potential for more resource_groups down the road and data normalization ... Option 2 is the best solution.
